# Extension Methods in .NET não funciona

Tags: c#, namespace, extension-method

Estou tentando criar um `Extension Methods` para a classe `string`. Ele não está aparecendo.

Minha classe com o método de extensão:

```
namespace MEUPROJETO.Extension
{
    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static string PrimeiraLetraDeCadaPalavraMiuscula(this string frase)
        {
            frase = frase.ToLower();

            System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

            return cultureinfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(frase);

        }
    }
}
```

Classe onde tento usa-lo:

```
namespace MEUPROJETO.Teste
{
   public static class TesteExt
   {
       public static void teste( )
       {
         string catdescription = "TESTANDO a frase nessa STRING.";

         catdescription = catdescription.PrimeiraLetraDeCadaPalavraMiuscula();
       }
   }
}
```

Ele não consegue nem compilar, diz que o método não existe, como faço para ele aparecer?

O namespace influencia?

Comment: Tem que indicar o namespace onde o *Extension Method* é declarado: `using MEUPROJETO.Extension`

Comment: Obrigado! Coloca como resposta que eu marco vc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou colocando a resposta que o ramaral colocou nos comentários, quando ele criar a resposta dele aqui eu marco a dele como resposta correta.

A solução é adicionar o namespace `using MEUPROJETO.Extension` onde quero usar os métodos.